# Add methods to category (from github)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I have a repository via cocoapods. This repository is a category. How can I add methods without sacrificing the updates? Can I subclass a category? In particular, these methods depend on other methods of the category, so I can not create a new category.
Suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a category, those methods are implemented for all instances of the object.

If you create a new category, the first one is not overridden or anything like that, they coexist, so as long as you import the headers for the first category you shouldn't run into any issues.

For example, let's say you are using this category imported in a pod:

```
@inteface NSObject (Helper)
-(void)help;
@end
```

And your own category in a new file:

```
#import "NSObject+Helper.h"

@interface NSObject (SuperHelper)
-(void)superHelp;
@end

@implementation NSObject (SuperHelper)
-(void)superHelp{
  [self help]; // No Issues here
  // Do more stuff
}
@end
```